# PFInstallation not up to date when receiving notifications in app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification

So I'm trying to do custom notification management, and everything works fine if the app is in the background, but if the user receives a notification when in the app, the current installation doesn't seem to be updated to reflect what is in parse, I've tried fetching and that doesn't seem to update just return the data of the local variable.

```
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()

    installation.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
    if let fetchedInstallation = object as? PFInstallation{
        print("fetched badge \(fetchedInstallation.badge)")
        print("local \(installation.badge)")
        // make sure app badge is updated to reflect total
    }
```

this is in the did receive remote notification in appdelegate. the print statement prints the local badge number from the beginning of when the app was launched, unless a notification comes in when in background then the installation updates.

Example: If the app is open and the PFInstallation badge was at 7 it will stay at 7 until a notification comes in while the app isn't in foreground. I can launch the app at any point, but as long as the app is running when it intercepts a notification the installation won't update. Then when the app is terminated or in background and a notification comes in the installation will update to the current data stored on parse.

So question is how would I make sure that the PFInstallation is updated correctly to reflect what is on parse while the app is in the foreground.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue. Hoping to hear from Parse folk soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to iOS badge numbers specifically, have you tried setting the badge value directly when the notification is received in the foreground? If you are using handlePush:, it may take care of this automatically for you.

Comment: Not exactly I'm talking about the PFInstallation.badge used in parse. The PFInstallation is being used to keep track of the total number of notifications   via [badge: "Increment"] in the push data. Since notifications can be coming from multiple sources, and I want to make sure that this app badge always represents the amount of notifications left uncheck in the app, similar to Mail. handlePush unfortunately just displays an alert to the user if they are in foreground.

Comment: Regardless of whether the app is in the foreground or background, the PFInstallation will have the correct value as the increment is performed by the server before the push is sent.

Comment: Now, you could manually update the badge if the app is in the foreground, but that would also update the PFInstallation. As long as you don't save the installation locally after doing this, this shouldn't update the server side value. With that said, this may be a good candidate for opening as an issue against the Parse iOS SDK repository on GitHub for further investigation.

Comment: Okay, because as of right now Increment does update parse on the server side, but as long as the app is in foreground the PFInstallation local object wont update until a notification is received while the app is in background. Thank you for the advice.